# Path entanglement

Tags: quantum-entanglement

Two particles can be polarization entangled. When one measures the first one to be horizontal. the other one is perpendicular. But how are two particles path - entangled?

Answer (score 0):

There are four path - one particle will take paths 1 or 2, the other 3 or 4.  If I find a particle in path 1, the other will be in path 4, if I measure the first in path 2, the second will be in path 3. -- Basicall, "polarization" is replaced by one of two paths.

Beyond that, this kind of correlation has very little to do with entanglement. Put for the purpose of this analogy, this gives the right analogy

Comment: Thank you Norbert! But I read an article where SPDC photons are entangled and there were only two paths. If there are only two paths does this exclude path entanglement?

Comment: @Mercury *Where* did you read that?  This way this is not very instructive.